# Why is Cr²⁺ is a good reducing agent but Mn³⁺ is a good oxidising agent?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds, transition-metals, reduction-potential, crystal-field-theory

The question is the same as the title states. In my textbook,<sup>[NCERT Chemistry I for Class 12 , pg no 217.]</sup> the following is written

> $\ce{Cr^{2+}}$ gets converted to $\ce{Cr^{3+}}$ as the +3 oxidation state has half-filled $\mathrm{t_{2g}}$ orbitals; thus it is a good reducing agent.
>
> On the other hand $\ce{Mn^{3+}}$ gets converted to $\ce{Mn^{2+}}$ as its +2 oxidation state has a half-filled d-subshell.

Now my questions are:

- Why can't the $\mathrm{t_{2g}}$ argument be used for $\ce{Mn}$?
- Why can't the half-filled $\mathrm{d}$-orbital argument be used for $\ce{Cr}$?

$\ce{Mn^3+}$ could be oxidized to $\ce{Mn^4+}$, which would have a half-filled $\mathrm{t_{2g}}$ set. As oxidation and reduction both can take place in aqueous medium, why wouldn't $\mathrm{t_{2g}^3}$ or $\mathrm{d^3}$ configuration be more stable than $\mathrm{d^5}$ configuration in aqueous medium?

A similar observation is made in case of $\ce{Fe^2+}$ and $\ce{Cr^2+}$, where it observed that $\ce{Cr^2+}$ is more powerful reducing agent than $\ce{Fe^2+}$ (due to reasons explained above).

If possible, I would like to see the crystal field splitting calculations that show this to be the case.

Comment: since you have talked about aqueous solution there is term enthalpy which dominates overall change. the difference is hydration enthalpy!

Comment: Duplicates don't necessarily have to be done in chronological order, see e.g. the answers at https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4611/16683, but anyway I don't plan to pronounce on which one should be closed as the other (not right now, at least; that can be a decision for later). My main point was that the questions are very similar.

Comment: http://ncert.nic.in/textbook/pdf/lech108.pdf link for the textbook

Answer (score -1):

> Why can't the $\mathrm{t_{2g}}$ argument be used for $\ce{Mn}$ ?

Because the number of $\mathrm{t_{2g}}$ electrons is not changing upon going from $\ce{Mn^3+}$ to $\ce{Mn^2+}$.  In both $\ce{Mn^2+}$ and $\ce{Mn^3+}$ there are 3 $\mathrm{t_{2g}}$ electrons.  I think the point they are trying to make with $\ce{Cr^3+}$ being half filled is that there are 3 $\mathrm{t_{2g}}$ electrons and no $\mathrm{e_g}$ electrons.  $\ce{Mn^3+}$ and $\ce{Mn^2+}$ both have $\mathrm{e_g}$ electrons.

You could make a similar argument for $\ce{Mn^3+}$ being oxidized to $\ce{Mn^4+}$, which would have half filled $\mathrm{t_{2g}}$ and empty $\mathrm{e_g}$.

> Why can't the half-filled d-orbital argument be used for Cr?

Because neither $\ce{Cr^3+}$ nor $\ce{Cr^2+}$ has a half filled d subshell.  $\ce{Cr^3+}$ has 3 electrons while $\ce{Cr^2+}$ has 4 electrons.

Comment: I was asking why not $\ce{Cr^+}$.

Comment: And actually, $\ce {Cr^2+} $ also has 3 $\ce {t_2g}$ electrons.

Comment: would Cr+ be d5 or s1d4?

Comment: i don't know why it would be s1d4 as d5 would be completely half filled and s is in the outer shell

Comment: from slide 16 here: http://alpha.chem.umb.edu/chemistry/ch371/documents/2.Chromiumacetate_001.pdf it seems like Cr(I) is s1d4

Comment: Won't Cr5+ be at d5 as well? How do we use that argument only for Mn3+->Mn2+ ?

Comment: Why not Mn3+->Mn4+? Then this would become a half filled t2g , right? Why can't we apply this argument?

Comment: Answer in incomplete